# How to print a javascript variable in a html element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The below code dynamically creates a span element. This part works.

I am having trouble with altering the name of every new element with an incrementing javascript counter variable.

```
<script>

var count = 0;

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#addTag").click(function() {
        count++;
        $("#tags").append("<span id='tag'> <input type='text' name='tag[" + count + "]' /> </span>");
    });
});

</script>
```

The desired result would be:

```
<span id='tag'> <input type='text' name='tag[0]'/> </span>   
<span id='tag'> <input type='text' name='tag[1]'/> </span>    
<span id='tag'> <input type='text' name='tag[2]'/> </span>
```

etc.. depending on the number of elements I choose to create.

Comment: What is the actual result?

Comment: As mentioned, there are multiple elements having same 'id' attribute as 'tag'. This is a bad practice.

Comment: Please read about `HTML` attributes, you can't have same `id` attribute.

Comment: It works fine, what's the desired o/p

Comment: look this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/on2h2Ltc/ everything seems to work just fine

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
This is a self executing function, it'll execute automatically 
when the js file is loaded.
*/    var Tags = (function() {
        var container = null, count = 0;

        return {
            init: function() {
                container = $("#tags");
            },
            addTag: function() {
                count += 1;
                // like many others mentioned, I've changed the id="tag"
                // to class="tag", because id should be a unique 
                // value on a given page
                container.append('<span class="tag"><input type="text" name="tag['+count+']"</span>');
            }
        };

    })();

    $(document).ready(function() {
        // Once document has loaded, call the init() function
        // so that the variable container will be assigned $("#tags").
        Tags.init();

        $("#addTag").click(function()   {
            Tags.addTag();
        });
    });
```

This is a cleaner method of doing it, without polluting the `globalscope` or in this case `jquery's document ready` scope with our arbitrary variables.

P.S: Your code works just fine, I just showed you a cleaner method, and the correct way of doing it (the `id` part).

Comment: OP has not trouble with added elems, no one knows what exactly OP's trouble

Comment: @Legendary Yea, he probably has issues when trying to interact with those appended items. `$("#tag")` would just return him the first element.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a closure to keep your count variable. On click this will be incremented each time the function is called.

```js
// Define our function called on click
var addEl = (function() {

  // These variables will be available in the function we return
  var count = 0;
  var myParent = $('#els');

  // Return our function.
  // This is a closure, our scope is maintained.
  return function() {
    myParent.append('<div name="tag[' + count + ']">' + count + '</div>');
    count++;
  };

})();

// Call our function on click.
// We can see that the counter will be incremented.
$('#addEl').on('click', addEl);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="addEl" type="button">Add</button>
<div id="els"></div>
```

Answer (score -2):

```js
$("#tags").append("<span id='tag"+ count +"'> <input type='text' name='tag" + count + "' /> </span>");
```

Comment: will you please care to explain?

Comment: The output from this doesn't match the "desired result" mentioned in the question.

Comment: Adding explanation will always improve the quality of your answer.